# Ktor cant create the table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, ktor

I created a Postgres database and now I want to create tables in my database.

This is my `main` function:

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(CIO, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        configureRouting()
        configureSerialization()
    }.start(wait = true)

    Database.connect(
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:12346/test",
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
        user = "postgres",
        password = "12345678"
    )

    transaction {
        SchemaUtils.create(UserTable)
    }
}
```

and this is my `UserTable.kt` class

```
object UserTable : IntIdTable(name = "users_tbl") {

    override val primaryKey: PrimaryKey
        get() = super.primaryKey

    val name = varchar(
        name = "name", length = 50
    )
    val lastName = varchar(
        name = "last_name", length = 50
    )
    val userName = varchar(
        name = "user_name", length = 20
    ).uniqueIndex()
}
```

When I run the main function it won't work.

Comment: `start(wait = true)` is a coroutine function(there should be a mark on the left in your IDE), it's not gonna finish execution until your program is working. You need to move your database initialization before that or inside configuration block.

Comment: Or you can use the `Netty` engine instead of `CIO` and don't pass `wait = true` argument to the `start` method.

Comment: with Netty, if the wait parameter is false main thread throws org.PostgreSQL.util.PSQLException
and when it is true I got the same result as before
@AlekseiTirman

Comment: What a `PSQLException` says?